# What's the maximum number of rank upgrades per level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have upgraded a level to rank 10, and am wondering if there is an upper limit to the number of upgrades I can apply to a particular level.

Comment: I don't think there are upper limits.  I currently have one at 41.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not appear to be one.  (Based upon in-game experience, and anecdotal evidence of others.)

Comment: What has brought you to this conclusion? In-game experience, searching online, et cetera?

Comment: @wipqozn Updated to reflect that it is based upon my experience and that of others. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've got one up to 88 and haven't yet hit a limit

Answer (score 1):

If there is a limit, it is higher than 149.

[image]

Comment: Wow. That's pretty high!