# What is the max level rank upgrade

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My plan is to rank up levels one by one starting at the button and working my way up.
But now I'm at rank 24 on the 1st level and there's no sign of stopping anytime soon so I'm starting to wonder if the ranks are infinite and I should change my strategy

Answer (score -1):

The question has been asked and answered here already: [What's the maximum number of rank upgrades per level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148519/whats-the-maximum-number-of-rank-upgrades-per-level)

But the gist of it is that there is no known limit on ranks at this time.

Comment: Then, please, flag it as a duplicate. That's what the flagging system is for.